# Catch the killer

Tags: word

The murderer has fled the scene, you have a feeling he will try to leave the country. You get access to his credit card records and see that he has recently spent £500 on flights at Getaway Travel Agency. You immediately rush to the shop to inspect their records.

Unfortunately, Getaway is a very old-fashioned Travel Agency and they still use hand-written tickets with carbon-copies. Even worse, the staff have no memory of the man who bought the ticket and the carbon copy has not worked very well.

All you can see for the departure airport is:

```
THE
```

"The what?" you ask the manager.

"I don't know," says the manager, looking puzzled. "We always write-in the full name of the Departure airport in that box".

Being the genius that you are, you immediately  dispatch your men to the correct airport where he is arrested boarding the plane.

Which airport?

Comment: Given that he's trying to leave "the country", and we must be in that country, what country is it? Or would that give too much away? Edit: Looks like I might know the country, anyway

Comment: @Joe, it sounds like you've been a jolly clever chap - or is that giving too much away?

Comment: I have, but I can't find a matching airport. The best I can get is ... ooh

Comment: Why is "THE" in full caps and left aligned if its supposed to come in the middle of a word?

I feel like you should have gone with the Brazilian answer given the way you introduced the handwritten note.

Comment: @DiscOH This is virtually the same as Michael's comment below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Most likely, Southend.
>
>  The killer paid the ticket in pounds, so we're probably in England. The only international airport with 'the' in its name, is *London Southend Airport*.
>  All other [airports in the UK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_the_United_Kingdom_and_the_British_Crown_Dependencies) containing 'the' are private, military, or local.
>
>  Another option would be *St. Catherine International Airport* in Egypt. It contains 'the' as well and Egypt uses the pound, like England does. *(Hat tip to [Ergwun](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5081/ergwun)).*
>
>  I haven't been able to find any other airports with 'the' in its name in a country using the pound as its currency.

Comment: Well done! I didn't expect it to take this long for anyone to work it out!

Comment: Well, there are also [Netherthorpe Airfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherthorpe_Airfield), [Hethel Airport](http://it.flightaware.com/live/airport/EGSK/scheduled), [RAF Weston-on-the-Green](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAF_Weston-on-the-Green) and [Airfield Camp Netheravon](http://www.army.mod.uk/aviation/28134.aspx)

Comment: Most of them are military tough, the only available remains Hethel Airport

Comment: Yep, actually also Hethel [is military](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAF_Hethel) (and also dismissed in 1948)

Comment: @Lefty If this is the answer, shouldn't the departure airport box have said "_________THE"? (where underscores are spaces)

Comment: Well, there is *some* space to the left. If I'd put any more it would have been too easy - and SQB only took about 20 minutes to get it as it was!

Comment: There's also St Catherine International Airport in Eqypt, where the currency is also pounds.

Comment: @Ergwun You are right, I totally missed that.

Comment: @Ergwun Good spot - it was not aware of that wrinkle. As it happens though, I think SQB's answer is still the only valid one because I suspect you can't get an international flight from there for the equivalent of GBP43. (I've obviously now invited some one to find a cheap flight to Libya or somewhere...)

Comment: @Lefty Yeah, if it was Egyptian Pounds you would probably have needed to write E£500 or maybe even خَمْسمِائة ج.م :)

Answer (score 10):

You send your men to...

> [Senador Petrônio Portela Airport](http://www.world-airport-codes.com/brazil/senador-petrnio-portella-9213.html) in Teresina, Brazil - its airport code is "THE" (in the same way LA International is LAX)

Comment: WRONG! You're missing a vital clue too.

Comment: @Lefty not that wrong, actually. A flight on British Airways can be paid in pounds.

Comment: I'm sure that's true - but it was just intended to guide people toward a UK Civilian airport. Also, I did explicitly state that it was the full name of the airport, trying to steer people away from codes and informal, local names.

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

> [Thetford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_the_United_Kingdom_and_the_British_Crown_Dependencies)

Reasoning:

> We know that the killer spent £500, so we're dealing with a Pound currency. The most common of them is GBP, so we're looking for airports in the UK.
>
>   (I have checked airports in all other pound-currency countries, and none contain "THE" in upper or lowercase.
>
>   The only airport in the UK starting with "THE" is [Thetford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_the_United_Kingdom_and_the_British_Crown_Dependencies) in Norfolk

Comment: I was holding-out high hopes for you! Your statement that "No airport contains THE" is wrong. But you're on the right lines with "contains" though!

Comment: @Lefty Thorne contains all the letters, but there's not a big enough gap in the written THE for that

Comment: @Lefty edited, after I looked at another list of airfields (just UK ones, not world :P )

Comment: nice try, but Thetford is Military. SQB beat you to it!

Answer (score 3):

> The airport in question is 'Theodore' in eastern Australia - the only airport whose full name starts with 'The'

Comment: WRONG! You're missing a vital clue.

Answer (score 2):

Key word is "that box". Airport code is spelled backwards:

> Airport is (EHT) Rentschler Airport.

Comment: Nice try - but it's "full name of the departure airport".

Answer (score 0):

The name of the airport is

> "Departure".

Reasoning:

> It is written in upper case, so it seems to be a proper name and not just where the airplane departs from.

Comment: No, it really is an airport...

Answer (score 0):

is it..

> Heathrow Airport in England ? the word Heath means a wasteland or uncultivated land (the ROW is empty hence it's a HeathRow).

Comment: This is far more clever than my question - but wrong nonetheless!